# Not using verb in a sentence

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure

By the end of the century, **almost enough rail track to encircle** the world covered this small island, altering the nature of travel for ever and contributing to the industrial revolution.

This sentence is taken from a test question, I cannot understand why after the comma in the beginning of sentence there is not any verb. I mean it needs something like this. (There has been built almost enough rail track to encircle....)

Comment: *Almost enough rail track to encircle the world* is a noun phrase, the subject of the main clause verb *covered*.

Answer (score 3):

You're not parsing the sentence correctly. What you have bolded is only part of the sentence, it's not a subclause.

"almost enough rail track to encircle" is not correctly delimited.

Notice the similar structure with an example sentence:

> [The table cloth] **covered** [the table].
>
> [Almost enough rail track to encircle the world] **covered** [this small island].

"Covered" is the verb you're looking for.  Everything that comes before it is a noun phrase, which is being used (as a whole) as the subject of the sentence.